# Skew List-view along with scrollbar without Clipping

Tags: android, listview, android-canvas, matrix-inverse, skew

I have tried to skew listview by adding below line of code in the ondraw method of customListview.

```
  canvas.skew(0.08f, 0.0f);
```

When i do that, i get the below result.

[image]

If i do not skew listview, it is like below

[image]

so, when i scroll down the skewed listview it becomes like below

[image]

i am just not able to view the scrollbar thumb anymore. How can i make sure no part of listview or its scrollbar thumb gets clipped even when the listview is skewed.Is there any chance to get it right with matrix manipulations? Please help or direct me on what i can do for that.